# Java: NullPointerException thrown when JButton is clicked in the Flash Card Game

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jbutton

Details: It's a Flash Card game, each Card has question and answer.
QuizCard is the class of Cards having functions like getQuestion(), getAnswer(), setQuestion(), setAnswer() and two String Instances as question and answer. A parameterised constructor takes two strings, first as question and second as answer.
I saved questions and answers in a text file, where question and answer is separated by a "/". All new questions start from a new line.
E.g. -> What is the Capital of India?/New Delhi 
        Where is the Taj Mahal?/Agra
Rest of the code can be easily understood.

Problem: When the "nextButton" is clicked it throws a NullPointerException and doesn't change the text on the "nextButton".

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class QuizCardPlayer 
{

private JFrame frame;
private JTextArea display;
private boolean isAnswer = true;
private JButton nextButton;
private ArrayList<QuizCard> cardList;
private int currentCardIndex;

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    QuizCardPlayer player = new QuizCardPlayer();
    player.go();
}

public void go()
{
    frame = new JFrame("Quiz Card Player");
    display = new JTextArea(6,20);
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    Font bigFont = new Font("serif", Font.BOLD, 24);
    display.setFont(bigFont);
    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(display);
    scroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    display.setText("Lets Start!");
    JButton nextButton = new JButton("Show Question");

    mainPanel.add(scroller);
    mainPanel.add(nextButton);
    nextButton.addActionListener(new NextButtonListener());

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    JMenuItem loadMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Load card set");
    loadMenuItem.addActionListener(new LoadMenuListener());
    fileMenu.add(loadMenuItem);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
}

public class NextButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.print("Called!!");
       if(isAnswer)
       {
            nextButton.setText("Show Answer");
            if( currentCardIndex < cardList.size() )
            {
                display.setText(cardList.get(currentCardIndex).getQuestion());
                isAnswer = false;
            }
            else
            {
                display.setText("That was last Card.");
                nextButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            nextButton.setText("Next Card");
            display.setText(cardList.get(currentCardIndex).getAnswer());
            isAnswer = true;
            currentCardIndex++;
        }
    }
}

public class LoadMenuListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev)
    {
        JFileChooser openFile = new JFileChooser();
        openFile.showOpenDialog(frame);
        loadFile(openFile.getSelectedFile());
    }
}

public void loadFile(File loadFile)
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(loadFile));
        String line="";
        cardList = new ArrayList<QuizCard>();
        while( (line = reader.readLine()) != null )
        {
            String[] result = line.split("/");
            QuizCard card = new QuizCard(result[0] , result[1]);
            cardList.add(card);
            currentCardIndex=0;
        }
        reader.close();
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

I am novice in Java having a experience of just one month, any suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating `nextButton` as an instance variable of class `QuizCardPlayer`, but inside `go()` method, you initializing the local variable `nextButton` and adding `Listener` to this local copy, and adding this local copy of `nextButton` to the `mainPanel` (which is visible on the VIEW ).

Though the instance variable remains `null`, as you never did assigned it to anythingy, and you trying to access this `null` variable inside `NextButtonListener` class, as follows:

```
nextButton.setText("Show Answer");
```

**EDIT 1:**

Simply replace this line inside `go ()` method:

```
JButton nextButton = new JButton("Show Question");
```

to

```
nextButton = new JButton("Show Question");
```

This will work :-)

Comment: @PalkeshJain: Please see the edit, to the OP. I hope this will sort thingies out :-)